# Xcode 6.3 Bug - Cannot create IBOutlet references or use custom UIViewControllers in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, storyboard, iboutlet

Ever since upgrading to Xcode 6.3 I can't create IBOutlet references and can't set my UIViewController items (or any other types of items for that matter) to my own custom implementations.

The drop down under "Custom Class - Class" shows nothing but regular stock classes.

If I put in the class manually and the module manually it works, but I have to create my outlets in the most annoying way by ctrl+dragging the item into code.

I've tried a number of answers that have been on here including the magical 'remove derived data and restart' answer for everything.

Anyone else with this issue that can shed some light?

EDIT:

Have tried:

1. Uninstalling / reinstalling xcode
2. Deleting user data
3. Deleting derived data
4. Restarting after doing all of the above

Comment: Have you tried updating to Xcode 6.3.1? The 6.3 version has some interface builder bugs.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I'm using 6.3.1. got my version wrong. I've decided to delete it and reinstall. Let you know how it goes. Bit of a pain, as if programming isn't difficult enough at times :)

Comment: Long shot but - you don't mention trying 'Product / Clean'.

Comment: @AliBeadle I already tried this, sorry. Also tried full clean (folders etc)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the update to 6.3.1 is not the root cause - [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14130184/2466193) has some answers that may hold a clue if you have not already seen it.

Comment: Have already looked at all of those suggestions. It may not be 6.3.1, but my projects were all fine a few nights ago until I updated. If I find an answer I'll post back here.