# Why prepare segue function is not working?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I am making a simple app where there are two screens. One screen includes a list of colors. I am passing that color on the next page and showing it as a background color.
I am using table view to show list colors. And passing data using `performSegue`.
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var color: [UIColor] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createRandomColorArray()
    }
    
    func createRandomColorArray() {
        for _ in 0..<50 {
            color.append(createRandomColor())
        }
    }
    
    func createRandomColor() -> UIColor {
        let randomColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat.random(in: 0...1.0),
                                  green: CGFloat.random(in: 0...1.0),
                                  blue: CGFloat.random(in: 0...1.0),
                                  alpha: 1)
        return randomColor
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if(segue.identifier == "ToColorDetailsVC") {
            if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? ColorDetailsVC {
                destinationVC.color = sender as? UIColor
            }
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return color.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ColorCell") else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        cell.backgroundColor = color[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let color = color[indexPath.row]
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToColorDetailsVC", sender: color)
    }
}
```

When I click one one color it should take me to the next screen with color value. But it's not working. When I click a color, it's showing me error.

```
Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10ea53d88) to 'color_app.ColorDetailsVC' (0x104cb8f88).
2023-11-07 00:21:54.111745+0600 color_app[32335:306275] Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10ea53d88) to 'color_app.ColorDetailsVC' (0x104cb8f88).
Could not cast value of type 'UIViewController' (0x10ea53d88) to 'color_app.ColorDetailsVC' (0x104cb8f88).
CoreSimulator 857.13 - Device: iPhone 12 Pro Max (85A3BBC1-BE77-4A52-B71F-8ADD0F7911D1) - Runtime: iOS 16.1 (20B72) - DeviceType: iPhone 12 Pro Max
```

Comment: In Storyboard, the next VC is still a `UIViewController`, not a `ColorDetailsVC`, or it's wrongly set, re set it?

Comment: @Larme I named that `UIViewController` as a `ColorDetailsVC`. 
```class ColorDetailsVC: UIViewController {}```

Comment: I meant there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21995327/1801544 In the Storyboard

Comment: @Larme This is my storyboard https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wJK7ZQLHGRG8O4T6D0LlspJ61x8wksKw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Sabbir33 - tough to tell from your screen-cap, but it ***looks*** like you have the Segue connected from `Colors` scene (likely `class Colors: UIViewController`), but the code you posted in your question is in `class ViewController: UIViewController`?

Comment: @DonMag Thank you. I fixed that issue. But now I am getting another issue. 
`2023-11-08 13:45:57.543496+0600 color_app[2357:79454] [Assert] UINavigationBar decoded as unlocked for UINavigationController, or navigationBar delegate set up incorrectly. Inconsistent configuration may cause problems. navigationController=<UINavigationController: 0x7f80eb01fe00>, navigationBar=<UINavigationBar: 0x7f80eaf0a370; frame = (0 59; 0 50); opaque = NO; autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000359dfa0>> delegate=0x7f80eb01fe00` 
the background color isn't loading in the second page.

Comment: @Sabbir33 - glad you fixed the issue. *"... now I am getting ..."* -- OK, that's an entirely different question, not suitable for discussion in comments.